# Combine multiple individual queries into one to get aggregated result in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have built two queries in ElasticSearch to get the counts for each error message. for example, the first query is to get how many error messages related to "was not found" error

```
GET /logstash*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "kubernetes.pod_name": "api"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "log": "error"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "log": {
                  "query": "was not found",
                  "operator": "and"

                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {"@timestamp": {
              "time_zone": "CET",
              "gt": "now-7d",
              "lte": "now"}}
          }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "aggs" : {
        "type_count" : {
            "value_count" : {
                "script" : {
                    "source" : "doc['log.keyword'].value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The second query is to get the count of error messages related to "Duplicate Entry" error

```
GET /logstash*/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "kubernetes.pod_name": "api"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "log": "error"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "log": {
                  "query": "Duplicate entry",
                  "operator": "and"

                }
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {"@timestamp": {
              "time_zone": "CET",
              "gt": "now-7d",
              "lte": "now"}}
          }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },

  "aggs" : {
        "type_count" : {
            "value_count" : {
                "script" : {
                    "source" : "doc['log.keyword'].value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My boss really wants me to combine these individual query into a one big query, then get the list of counts for each error messages in one output. Since we have a lot of error messages, which means we have to write each query for each error message, then we have to run each query to get the counts. Is there a way I can click one run to get the list of counts?

I have been trying use query string query and looking for solutions on either Stack Overflow and Documentation. However, there is no luck

Answer (score 1):

You can use [filter aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) along with the `value_count` aggregation to combine these two queries. In both the queries, out of the 4 queries inside must clause only one differs. You can take this out and combine them with the two filter aggregations as below:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "kubernetes.pod_name": "api"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "log": "error"
              }
            },
            {
              "range": {
                "@timestamp": {
                  "time_zone": "CET",
                  "gt": "now-7d",
                  "lte": "now"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "not_found_count": {
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "log": {
            "query": "was not found",
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count": {
          "value_count": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['log.keyword'].value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "duplicate_entry_count": {
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "log": {
            "query": "Duplicate entry",
            "operator": "and"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count": {
          "value_count": {
            "script": {
              "source": "doc['log.keyword'].value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have new post about Kibana, however, there is no one can help me out, could you take a look at it, maybe you know the answer. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55013552/how-to-get-the-counts-of-log-messages-based-on-the-error-type-in-elasticsearch-v