# How to get the counts of log messages based on the error type in Elasticsearch visualization

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have some sample data on the Elasticsearch, which looks like the following:

[image]

I am using the data table in the Visualize section to get the counts for  each error type, for example: it should output

`Error: Update failed for online booking with id`, count is 5.

Not the count 1 for different id of the same error type.

What I have done is to build a query to output the counts for each error type, which looks like this:

[image]

However, when I save the query as the saved search, then visualize it as data table, it still have the same issue as above.

I was thinking to only save the output of that query as saved search, one issue is that the output is too verbose, has a lot of information I don't really need.

Any suggestions please !

Comment: Please add a sample document to the question.

Comment: @Nishant, Sorry, it is using my company data. I cannot show more. However, it is the same problem you helped me in another post, which build the query. However, in this case, I want to use the data table in Visualize of the Kibana to get the same result. I was thinking about using the scripted field to create the each error type on the fly, But someone don't suggest me to do it.

Comment: Well I understand that but I need to look at the mapping/doc, then only I'll be able to help. For sample doc you can replace the actual content by something else other than the company data.

Comment: @NishantSaini Sorry, I still dont understand what you really need. like what is the mapping/doc? Since all the files are stored in Kibana,

Comment: Use this to get mapping of index `GET /<index_name>/_mapping`